# Find and print a regex with sed, awk, perl

Tags: regex, sed, awk

i can't seem to find a way to take something like this:

```
some name blah blah blah:12000 some numbers 3746 4857 23490 324989 and in 
the end THIS 3456/45678
```

IT'S NOT ALWAYS IN THE END, COULD BE ANYWHERE IN A LINE...

So, in one line there are a lot of numbers and everything else, and I need to extract only
this:

Output:

```
3456/45678
```

I have tried, SED, AWK...and everything i tried succesfully extracts all the numbers, but I need only that pattern...

Has anyone any ideas?

Thanks to all in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using egrep:

```
egrep -o '[0-9]+/[0-9]+' <<< "$s"
3456/45678
```

Comment: My bad, tried with the source variable, works without it...thanks a lot, will accept the answer as soon as it gets possible (in 5 minutes)...thanks again...